# Efficiently add a large number of dynamic components to a view

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an application which creates a large number of dynamic components (up to ~200 cells in a grid)

```js
//get component factory to create components
let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver
                  .resolveComponentFactory(CellComponent);
//for each cell with data
for (let d of data) {
  //create host view with component
  let cell = this.grid.createComponent(factory);
  //set grid position
  cell.instance.column = "_" + d.day;
  cell.instance.row =    "_" + d.time;
  //data entries inside the cell
  cell.instance.contents =     d.data;
}
```

I am running into a performance issue where the view is being checked and updated for every component.

Is there a way to insert multiple components into a view at once, or without checking each?

Comment: why do you create new component for each cell? does it do something special ?

Comment: yes each cell has a number of different items in it, plus each cell is being placed on a grid depending on its values. Each cell has a number of functions it performs too

Comment: I managed to reduce the number of times the view is checked a lot by using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush` but the view still gets checked a lot more than it needs to

Comment: I just try to suggest you to use this strategy, but if you done it already, you may try to detach your changeDetection, and do it manually